# can you add an SSD without removing the original HD

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replacing SuperDrive with secondary storage?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/replacing-superdrive-with-secondary-storage)

I just bought my first Mac (MBP) and Id like to add an SSD drive without pulling or replacing my original factory drive.  Is it possible to fit and use both types?  early 2011 MBP 13.3 2.3 GHZ.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to keep the HDD and add an SSD, [articles](http://osxdaily.com/2010/05/19/install-an-ssd-into-the-optical-drive-slot-on-a-macbook-pro/) document ways to replace the Superdrive with a SSD. If the goal is to keep all the machine's factory-installed parts intact, it would appear you would have to use an external SSD.